# Expecting distinct output from array seperated by commas

Tags: php

i want to fetch distinct values from an array and also those value should be separated by commas
like English,German,French but what i have got is EnglishFrenchGerman.

```
 <?php 
    $cmd = mysql_query("select language from lang where dispname = 'Sk'");
    while($out = mysql_fetch_array($cmd))
    {
    $res = array_unique($out);  
    $row = implode(",",$res);
    echo "$row";
        }           
    ?>
```

Comment: I wonder if that code really works...

Comment: as i already explained have this code  return values without commas but i am expecting values separated with commas so if u could help

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot see why the code does not do what you expect then dump data out during the processing. Try this :-

```
<?php 
    $cmd = mysql_query("select language from lang where dispname = 'Sk'");
    while($out = mysql_fetch_array($cmd))
    {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($out,true) . '</pre>';
        $res = array_unique($out);  
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($res,true) . '</pre>';
        $row = implode(",",$res);
        echo $row;
    }           
?>
```

Comment: That was not supposed to fix it, it was supposed to show you what might be wrong. If you cannot work it out, then post the results by editing your question please.